# How does the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra act on its Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on $G$ by
\begin{align}
\xi.f(X) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(e^{t\xi}X), \ \xi \in \mathfrak{g}, X \in G, f \in C^{\infty}(G).
\end{align}
Do we have $\xi.(fg)=(\xi.f) g + f \xi.g$, $f, g \in C^{\infty}(G)$?

Let $U(\mathfrak{g})$ be the enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\xi, \eta \in U(\mathfrak{g})$. How to compute $(\xi \eta).f$, where $f \in C^{\infty}(G)$? Let $1$ be the identity element in $U(\mathfrak{g})$. What is the result of $1.f$, $f \in C^{\infty}(G)$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you mean by "acting on $G$". What you write out in the beginning of the question is just the natural identification of $\mathfrak g$ with the space of right invariant vector fields on $G$. Of course, any such vector field acts as a derivation on $C^\infty(G)$ (as any vector field does), so you do get $\xi\cdot(fg)=(\xi\cdot f)g+f\xi\cdot g$. This means that you interpret any element of $\mathfrak g$ as a first order differential operator acting on $C^\infty(G)$.

Correspondingly, you get an identification of $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ as the space of all right invariant differential operators acting on $C^\infty(G)$. In this identification $1\cdot f =f$ and $(\xi\eta)\cdot f=\xi\cdot(\eta\cdot f)$, so you simply compose the two first order operators determined by $\xi$ and $\eta$ to get a second order operator. This is well defined by definition of the Lie bracket.

Comment: thank you very much. Sorry, I made a typo. I need to say "acting on $C^{\infty}(G)$" ( not "acting on $G$" ).

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for very nice answer. May I ask a question? Is there an analogue of Leibniz rule for $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$?

Comment: @user29422 : The Leibniz rules characterizes first order operators, so this is only valid for vector fields. For higher order operators there is no simple rule like that, you can for example easily compute $\xi\cdot (\eta\cdot (fg))$ from the Leibniz rules of the two fields. What you can do is characterizing higer order differential operators inductively, i.e. $D$ is an operator or order $k$ if and only if $g\mapsto D(fg)-fD(g)$ is an operator of order $k-1$.

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks you very much for kind reply. There is no simple Leibniz rule for element in the $U(\mathfrak{g})$. Do you think is it similar with $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ the center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$? I think the center is special so there might be some simple rule at least for it.

Comment: @user29422  I am not aware of anything in that direction. My feeling would be that the fact that higher order operators appear (also for the center) makes it impossible to have a simple analog of the Leibniz rule ther. (Also, the Leibniz rule here has nothing to do with the group structure ...)

Comment: @Andreas, I see! Thank you for your answer!